# Call Two Methods on Watch Function in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I need to call functions "getService" and "getTabs" on watch method. The problem is the other one gets called but the other one doesn't when i decided to change $route. Is there a problem in my code?

```
watch: {
    $route: "getService",
    $route: "getTabs"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call those 2 methods when the route changes:

```
watch: {
  '$route' () {
     this.getService()
     this.getTabs()
   }
}
```